# Can I create nested list in SlateJs?

Tags: javascript, slatejs, slate

I need to create nested list objects like :

```
1. Abc
2. def
    a. abc
        i. lmn
        ii. opq
    b. def
3. ghi
```

I am using Slate Js as my editor where when a user presses tab I have added the code where the node is updated with its level :

```
if (event.key === "Tab") {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      
      let currentNode = Editor.above(editor,{at : editor.selection})[0];
      if(currentNode.type === "listItem"){
      let newLevel = currentNode.level ? currentNode.level + 1 : 1;
     
      Transforms.setNodes(editor, {level : newLevel});
}}
```

Here the level is getting added to the node but I cannot nest this data into a tree structure as slateJs only allows three level of nesting of nodes and it needs a text key in the third level.

Answer (score 0):

You can. The trick is wrapping the text of a 'list item' node in a 'list item text' node (e.g. a `span` or `p`), as explained in this slate schema of [@prezly/slate-lists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@prezly/slate-lists#Schema). The subsequent nested list can now be added to the same 'list item' node as a 'list' node.